# highcharts does not appear in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, highcharts

i got a problem to displays my chart [jsfiddle chart](http://jsfiddle.net/suuuunto/XWAzD/) in the ie browsers. i have read all the stuff about commas, but i get no better result.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var chart;
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
renderTo: 'chart_risk_factors_var95',
backgroundColor:'#F7F7F7',
height:200,
plotBackgroundColor: null,
plotBorderWidth: null,
plotShadow: false
},

credits: {
enabled: false
},

tooltip: {
pointFormat: '<b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
percentageDecimals: 1
},

title:{
text:null    
},

plotOptions: {

pie: {
showInLegend: true,
dataLabels: { enabled: false }}
},

legend: {
layout: 'vertical',
align: 'right',
verticalAlign: 'middle'   
}, 

series: [{
type: 'pie',
name: 'risk factors',
data: [
        {name: 'Interest Exposure',y: <?php echo $data['total_exp_interest_pie'] ?>,color:'#3B8686'},
        {name: 'Equity Exposure',y: <?php echo $data['total_exp_equity_pie'] ?>,color:'#79BD9A'},
        {name: 'Fx Exposure',y: <?php echo $data['total_exp_fx_pie'] ?>,color:'#A8DBA8'},
        {name: 'Commodity Exposure',y: <?php echo $data['total_exp_commodity_pie'] ?>,color:'#CFF09E'}
]}]

});
});
```

I added also some php code to fill in the data.

What I am doing wrong?

Thx help,
suuuunto

Comment: I tested your example in IE7 and IE8 and works fine. Any specific steps to reproduce issue? Could you make sure that you have latest Highcharts library?

Comment: Which version of IE7 / IE8 do you use?

Comment: I debugged the code with the ie debugger and i get the same positive result for all ie version! I think it was something with disabling add-on's. Or the special version of ie in my office ;) thanks guys